# Can the double pendulum equations not be derived solely using Newtonian Mechanics (Newton's Laws of Motion)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I can't find an answer for whether the Double Pendulum equations can be derived solely using Newtonian Mechanics (Newton's Laws of Motion). The reason I ask for this answer is because wherever I go, I only see the Lagrangian solution. I am also aware that there are certain problems in Classical Mechanics that can't be solved solely using Newtonian Mechanics, so I wanted to know if this is one of those cases...

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for anything deeper? Usually "yes or no" questions aren't well received here.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I would also like to see the Newtonian Derivation as I can't find it anywhere on the internet and neither am I able to derive it myself using my limited knowledge...

Comment: Unfortunately at that point your question might be closed for asking for a calculation/derivation. What physics concepts are you confused about that are preventing you from solving the problem yourself? That would be a better thing to focus on here.

Comment: The recently posted answer gave me an idea of how to go about things, If I don't figure it out using even that, I will come back here or I will make another question post...

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The EOM's with NEWTON method are:

$$J^T\,M\,J\,\vec{\ddot{q}}=J^T\,\left(\vec{f}_a-M\,\vec{f}_z\right)\tag 1$$

where:

- $\vec q$ generalized coordinates
- $J=\frac{\partial\vec R}{\partial\vec q}$ the Jacobi matrix
- $\vec R$ Position vector
- M Mass Matrix
- $\vec{f}_a$ Applied force vector
- $\vec{f}_z=\frac{\partial(J\,\vec{\dot q})}{\partial\vec{q}}\,\vec{\dot q}$ fictitious force vector

**Double Pendulum equations**

[image]

generalized coordinates

$$\vec q=\left[ \begin {array}{c} \varphi _{{1}}\\ \varphi _
{{2}}\end {array} \right] 
$$

position vectors

$$\vec R_1=\left[ \begin {array}{c} L_{{1}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) 
\\ L_{{1}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
~,\vec R_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} L_{{2}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) +L
_{{1}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) \\ L_{{2}}
\cos \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) +L_{{1}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{1}}
 \right) \end {array} \right]
$$

Mass Matrix:

$$M_1=  \begin{bmatrix}
     m_1 & 0 \\
    0  & m_1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}~,M_2=  \begin{bmatrix}
     m_2 & 0 \\
    0  & m_2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$$

Applied Forces:

$$\vec f_{a1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    -m_1\,g \\
  \end{bmatrix}~,\vec f_{a2}\begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    -m_2\,g \\
  \end{bmatrix}$$

combine $$\vec R=\begin{bmatrix}
    \vec{R}_1 \\
    \vec{R}_2\\
  \end{bmatrix}~,M=\begin{bmatrix}
     M_1 & 0 \\
     0 & M_2 \\
   \end{bmatrix}~,\vec f_a=\begin{bmatrix}
    \vec{f}_{a1} \\
    \vec{f}_{a2}\\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

with equation (1) you obtain the equations of motion

**edit**

$$J=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} L_{{1}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) &0
\\  -L_{{1}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) &0
\\  L_{{1}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) &L_{{2}
}\cos \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) \\  -L_{{1}}\sin
 \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) &-L_{{2}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{2}}
 \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

$$\vec{f}_z=   \left[ \begin {array}{c} -L_{{1}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) {
\dot\varphi _{{1}}}^{2}\\ -L_{{1}}\cos \left( \varphi _
{{1}} \right) {\dot\varphi _{{1}}}^{2}\\ -L_{{1}}\sin
 \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) {\dot\varphi _{{1}}}^{2}-L_{{2}}\sin
 \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) {\dot\varphi _{{2}}}^{2}
\\ -L_{{1}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) {\dot
\varphi _{{1}}}^{2}-L_{{2}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) {\dot
\varphi _{{2}}}^{2}\end {array} \right] 
$$

$$J^T\,M\,J=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} {L_{{1}}}^{2}m_{{1}}+{L_{{1}}}^{2}m_{{2}}&L
_{{1}}m_{{2}}L_{{2}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{1}}-\varphi _{{2}} \right) 
\\ L_{{1}}m_{{2}}L_{{2}}\cos \left( \varphi _{{1}}-
\varphi _{{2}} \right) &{L_{{2}}}^{2}m_{{2}}\end {array} \right]
$$

$$J^T\,\vec f_a=\left[ \begin {array}{c} L_{{1}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) m_
{{1}}g+L_{{1}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{1}} \right) m_{{2}}g
\\ L_{{2}}\sin \left( \varphi _{{2}} \right) m_{{2}}
g\end {array} \right] 
$$

$$J^T\,M\,\vec f_z=\left[ \begin {array}{c} L_{{1}}m_{{2}}L_{{2}}{\dot\varphi _{{2}}}^{2}
\sin \left( \varphi _{{1}}-\varphi _{{2}} \right) 
\\ -L_{{2}}m_{{2}}L_{{1}}{\dot\varphi _{{1}}}^{2}\sin
 \left( \varphi _{{1}}-\varphi _{{2}} \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

Comment: This at least gives me an idea of how to proceed with the derivation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The double pendulum can be solved directly using Newton's laws of motion. However, I would imagine that it is easier to solve it using the Lagrangian formulation because the constraints (the lower pendulum is attached to the upper one) are more easily introduced. If you just wanted to use $F=ma$, you would have to figure out what force is being exerted at every moment in time by the joint between the two pendulums to keep them from coming apart.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! Also do you know where I can find the Newtonian derivation for the equations? I couldn't find it anywhere and I am having a hard time deriving it myself...