# Double Pendulum and newtonian mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, rotational-kinematics

I am searching for a way by which I can find the displacement vector of a double pendulum as functions of time.( without using lagrangian mechanics)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the double pendulum equations not be derived solely using Newtonian Mechanics (Newton's Laws of Motion)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/580949/can-the-double-pendulum-equations-not-be-derived-solely-using-newtonian-mechanic)

Comment: Yes...thanks a lot Mr.Amirhosein:)